# Intuitively grasp why these two events are independent

Tags: probability, intuition

Two well constructed dice are tossed. Let $A$ denote the event that the first die shows $2$ or $5$ and $B$ denote the event that the sum of the values of the numbers shown on the two tossed dice is $\ge7$.

**Are the events $A$ and $B$ independent or dependent?**

$P(A) = g/m = 2/6 = 1/3$

$P(B) = g/m = 21/36$

$P(A \cap B) = g/m = 7/36$

$P(A)P(B) = (1/3)(21/36) = 7/36$

Since $P(A)P(B) = P(A\cap B)$ we can conclude that the events $A$ and $B$ are independent.

If we would have chosen the numbers $3$ and $5$ instead of $2$ and $5$ in event $A$ then $P(A\cap B) \neq P(A)P(B)$. However, when choosing numbers whose sum equals $7$, like $1$ and $6$, we get that the events are independent.

The math clearly shows that the events are independent when certain numbers are picked, but is there **any intuitive way whatsoever of grasping why this is the case?**

I find the result very counter intuitive.

Any explanation of this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Often, the first step in such situations is to first explain why you find it counter intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be less surprising when phrased as the following equivalent problem:

> Suppose you roll two six sided dice whose faces are numbered $\pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 5$.
>
> Let $A$ be the event that the first die has magnitude $3$.
>
> Let $B$ be the event that the sum is positive.
>
> Are these events independent?

Comment: Thank you, this made it intuitively clear.

Answer (score 0):

What is the probability of getting $7$ or more when the first die shows $2$ or $5$?

What is the probability of getting $7$ otherwise?

Are they the same? Yes! Then, **no matter** if the first die shows $2$ or $5$ or it does not.

So, a more intuitive formula for independence would be

---

$$p(A\mid B)=p(A\mid B)$$
That is
$$\frac{p(AB)}{p(B)}=\frac{p(A\bar B)}{p(\bar B)}$$

But $p(A\mid B)=p(A)-p(AB)$ because $AB$ and $A\bar B$ are disjoint and their union is $A$. Also, $p(\mid B)=1-p(B)$. Therefore, the last equality can be written as:

$$\frac{p(AB)}{p(B)}=\frac{p(A)-p(AB)}{1-p(B)}$$
or
$$p(AB)-p(B)p(AB)=p(A)p(B)-p(AB)p(B)$$
and this is 
$$p(AB)=p(A)p(B),$$

---

the very definition of probabilistic independence.

Note that the formulas between the lines can be derived in reverse order, assuming that no involved probability is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the first die $X$ given the event $B$ the conditional probability of $P(X=2|B)$ has obviously diminished compared with $P(X=2)$ but $P(X=5\mid B)$ has augmented precisely as
much as the other diminished. 
So $$P(X\in \{2,5\}\mid B)=P(X\in \{2,5\})$$